# "Save to Drive" buttons can/need to be cleaned up manually?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, google-drive-api

Using https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive#javascript_api
In a VueJS app, like:

In `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {
    parsetags: 'explicit',
    lang: 'en-US'
  };
</script>
<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js' async defer></script>
```

In a component:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.gapi.savetodrive.go(`savetodrive-${this.id}`);
  },
}
```

The "Save to drive" buttons are rendered correctly, but on navigating away from the component (when the HTML element gets removed from the DOM), I start getting a lot of exceptions in the console (one per each button x times rendered):

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://drive.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Object.nz [as kq] (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.xh-S9KbEGSE.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQc/rs=AGLTcCNaUSRWzhd71dAsiMVOstVE3KcJZw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:150:257)
    at jz.send (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.xh-S9KbEGSE.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQc/rs=AGLTcCNaUSRWzhd71dAsiMVOstVE3KcJZw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:148:261)
    at Fz (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.xh-S9KbEGSE.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQc/rs=AGLTcCNaUSRWzhd71dAsiMVOstVE3KcJZw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:152:349)
    at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.xh-S9KbEGSE.O/m=gapi_iframes,gapi_iframes_style_common/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQc/rs=AGLTcCNaUSRWzhd71dAsiMVOstVE3KcJZw/cb=gapi.loaded_0:152:259
```

Is there something I'm missing? Something else I need to take care of when destroying the view?

Note that the filepath for the button is under the same server, the path is specified as relative, so there's no CORS involved for downloading the file, everything works ok, the only issue I have is the JS errors.

Comment: im guessing this google code creates some sort of iframe. I cant find any API doc on how to unload this stuff

Comment: Yes, it does create an iframe for every button.

Comment: Have you tried destroying your HTML using `v-show` directive? This way the HTML would still be there with `display:none` and you should not get any console errors.

Comment: Why not import the Google API only into the component where the buttons exist? That way when you create or destroy the component all the button specific code goes with it?

Comment: `v-show` is only hiding the content not destroying it. That's not feasible as I will need to keep every component.

Comment: Importing the Google API into the component where the buttons exist doesn't make too much of a difference, since the buttons are in a table, that is paginated, on page change, the ones from the previous page start to throw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each "Save to Drive" button will append 2 elements to the body which will remain after leaving the page. A solution would be to manually remove them before leaving the route.

[image: "ins" elements to remove]

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  try {      
    // Remove all elements created by Save to Drive
    const insList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ins'));
    for (let i = 0; i < insList.length; i += 1) {
      // Remove the iframe div
      insList[i].previousSibling.remove();
      // Remove ins element
      insList[i].remove();
    }
  } finally {
    next();
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying your html like this, it should get rid of the iframes, but then you will have to load some content in your document of course...

```
var AnotherNode = document;
while (AnotherNode.hasChildNodes()) {
    AnotherNode.removeChild(AnotherNode.lastChild);
}
```